# Kobuki : eigen unaligned array

Tags: turtlebot, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am currently working with a Turtlebot 2 with a Kobuki base.
I have a problem when I want to test the auto docking following the tutorial here : http://ros.org/wiki/kobuki/Tutorials/Testing%20Automatic%20Docking

When I try to launch the script compact.launch I have the following error :

```
[ INFO] [1367937642.195095811]: waitForService: Service [/kobuki/load_nodelet] is now available.

Warning: class_loader::class_loader_private: SEVERE WARNING!!! A namespace collision has occured with plugin factory for class kobuki::AutoDockingNodelet. New factory will OVERWRITE existing one. This situation occurs when libraries containing plugins are directly linked against an executable (the one running right now generating this message). Please separate plugins out into their own library or just dont link against the library and use either class_loader::ClassLoader/MultiLibraryClassLoader to open.

         at line 180 in /opt/ros/groovy/include/class_loader/class_loader_core.h
nodelet: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:69: Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = double, int Size = 4, int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion (reinterpret_cast<size_t>(array) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****" failed.

[FATAL] [1367937643.023125331]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1367937643.023446055]: Service call failed!
[kobuki-2] process has died [pid 10051, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=kobuki __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/09289394-b724-11e2-a331-446d57c545ae/kobuki-2.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/09289394-b724-11e2-a331-446d57c545ae/kobuki-2*.log
[mobile_base-3] process has died [pid 10052, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet load kobuki_node/KobukiNodelet kobuki mobile_base/odom:=odom mobile_base/joint_states:=joint_states __name:=mobile_base __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/09289394-b724-11e2-a331-446d57c545ae/mobile_base-3.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/09289394-b724-11e2-a331-446d57c545ae/mobile_base-3*.log
[dock_drive-4] process has died [pid 10110, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet load kobuki_auto_docking/AutoDockingNodelet kobuki dock_drive/odom:=odom dock_drive/core:=mobile_base/sensors/core dock_drive/dock_ir:=mobile_base/sensors/dock_ir dock_drive/motor_power:=mobile_base/commands/motor_power dock_drive/velocity:=mobile_base/commands/velocity __name:=dock_drive __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/09289394-b724-11e2-a331-446d57c545ae/dock_drive-4.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/09289394-b724-11e2-a331-446d57c545ae/dock_drive-4*.log
```

In the same way when I launch the file minimal.launch of the turtlebot_bringup package I get the same error :

```
    nodelet: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:69: Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = float, int Size = 4, int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion (reinterpret_cast<size_t>(array) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****" failed.
[FATAL] [1367936008.172819198]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1367936008.174865951]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1367936008.175274112]: Service call failed!
[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-5] process has died [pid 14661, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=mobile_base_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/16ea5958-b720-11e2-937d-446d57c545ae/mobile_base_nodelet_manager-5.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/16ea5958-b720-11e2-937d-446d57c545ae/mobile_base_nodelet_manager-5*.log
[mobile_base-6] process has died [pid 14678, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet load kobuki_node/KobukiNodelet mobile_base_nodelet_manager mobile_base/odom:=odom mobile_base/enable:=enable mobile_base/disable:=disable mobile_base/joint_states:=joint_states __name:=mobile_base __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/16ea5958-b720-11e2-937d-446d57c545ae/mobile_base-6.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/16ea5958-b720-11e2-937d-446d57c545ae/mobile_base-6*.log
[cmd_vel_mux-8] process has died [pid 14829, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet load cmd_vel_mux/CmdVelMuxNodelet mobile_base_nodelet_manager __name:=cmd_vel_mux __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/16ea5958-b720-11e2-937d-446d57c545ae/cmd_vel_mux-8.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/16ea5958-b720-11e2-937d-446d57c545ae/cmd_vel_mux-8*.log
[bumper2pointcloud-9] process has died [pid 14929, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet load kobuki_bumper2pc/Bumper2PcNodelet mobile_base_nodelet_manager bumper2pointcloud/pointcloud:=mobile_base/sensors/bumper_pointcloud bumper2pointcloud/cliff_events:=mobile_base/events/cliff bumper2pointcloud/bumper_events:=mobile_base/events/bumper __name:=bumper2pointcloud __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/16ea5958-b720-11e2-937d-446d57c545ae/bumper2pointcloud-9.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/16ea5958-b720-11e2-937d-446d57c545ae/bumper2pointcloud-9*.log
```

I read things about this error, and in this ticket https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5164 people said that you should add

```
public: EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW;
```

in some of the files, but I don't really know in which files I should do that.
Can someone help me ?

Caroline

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62310/kobuki-:-eigen-unaligned-array/) by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 395 on 2013-05-07

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-05-22**:
Btw, did you solved your problems with bumper in costmap? I updated my answer with all that I learned in a recent work. I'm curious about this issue ^_^

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-06-03**:
I replied to the post about bumpers in costmap. Sorry for this late reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, it's the same problem you asked about in the other question. It should get solved after updating packages to the latest version (0.3.8) that I released yesterday. It's not still on shadow-fix, so you must wait maybe a while.

If you are not using shadow-fix packages, you will need to wait around a week to get the update.

Please tell me if the problem persist after updating.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-05-22**:
Thanks, I didn't test the update for the moment because I am not using shadow-fix packages, but I will keep you up to date about the test. But do you think the  fix would also solve the problem about auto-docking ?

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-05-29**:
I am having the same problem here. What is strange is that it worked perfectly for a while and suddenly stopped working today. Could you let us know when the debs will be available ?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-05-29**:
Curious... did you switch from a 32 to a 64 bits Ubuntu? Or did you start using turtlebot_bringup instead of kobuki_node? Both things can explain that the error appears.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-05-29**:
btw, the patch that fix this is ready in shadow-fix, in case you want to install it asap.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-05-29**:
I updated the debs. It worked better. But sometimes, the error still occurs. I am not sure whether it is related to it or not, but most of the time, it seems that it happens after the laptop losts the wifi connexion with the workstation computer on which I launch the action client.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-05-29**:
But I didn't change neither the workstation computer, nor the laptop, nor the laptop OS, which is a 32 bits.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-05-30**:
It seems that I didn't manage to install the shadow-fixed packages. I tried to update again today and got a message error. Could you explain me how to do this update from shadow-fix ?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-06-02**:
Edit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list file and replace line "deb http://packages.yujin.com/ros/ubuntu precise main" by
"deb http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu precise main". Then apt-get update and upgrade

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-02**:
Ok, that's what I did. Don't know why it didn't work the first time, but now it is ok. Thank you.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-06-02**:
Welcome!  got fixed the Eigen-problem?

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-02**:
I am going to test it in a few minutes. I'll let you know. :)

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-02**:
Well I tested it right now, and it still occurs some times. Maybe I am doing something I shouldn't ? I wrote my own script instead of using activate.launch.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-02**:
I can confirm something, it does only happen after the turtlebot has lost the connection with the workstation (on which my script which replaces activate.launch turns), when I try to bring it back to work. By the way, clock sync with ntpdate seems to fix it.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-06-03**:
Happy to hear you solved the problem, but... I'm getting lost!!! I mean, looks like two different issues; i cannot figure out what relates the eigen problem with machines synchronization. The error that you fix with ntpdate is still  "Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptio..."?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-06-03**:
If so, I completely misunderstood the problem!!!  But anyway, it made us fix another issue ^_^. I will ask to our local guru to get a deeper understanding of what's going on. Thanks!

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-03**:
I will try to make the error occur again to post it here. I post it in Answer, because there is not enough place in comments. :s But I don't know either why time sync does solve the problem. But since it does, I keep using this solution. :)

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-06-03**:
I managed to reproduce the error systematically: I just need to call kobuki_auto_docking standalone.launch! So we fixed it: it's the same problem we already fixed but in a different place! I'll make another release asap. Thanks for helping us fix it!

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-04**:
I tried kobuki_auto_docking standalone.launch (I launched kobuki_node minimal.launch too because standalone.launch didn't seem to be meant to be launched alone, and sent an 'enable' message in dock_drive/mode_shift topic ). I had the same results as before : sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-06-04**:
Yep...  a bit confusing. Here standalone means that it launches its own nodelet manager, so it doesn't need the mobile_base_nodelet_manager to be already up and running. Semantics...

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-06-04**:
mmm...  It should always fail...  estrange. Anyway, the fix is now being compiled, so it should be available soon.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-05**:
Ok. Will the sources be available too ?

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-06-06**:
Hi jorge ! For the last fix you did, in which file did you  add the line "EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_NEW" ? I found it in the dock_drive.hpp but I think it's not the last fix, isn't it ? Thanks for kelp

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-06-06**:
Yes,  there is. Previous fix was in kobuki_bumper2pc.hpp.  It's all working now?

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-06-06**:
For bumper2pc it works fine. But for auto-docking, I have the line in dock_drive.hpp as it is in the shadow fix source but I still have the same error when I launch kobuki_auto_docking standalone.launch. @Lucile : Did you manage to solve your problem ?

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-06**:
No, I still have the same error and I am using sources files from github now because I am working on the autodocking algorithm...

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-06-06**:
Lucile: groovy-devel or hydro-devel?  Did you compile with --pre-clean?     CarolineQ: Did u apt-get upgrade today?

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-06**:
I am using Groovy. I didn't upgrade today. But as you asked, I will. I didn't compile with --pre-clean since I only recompiled the kobuki_auto_docking package with catkin in order to get the libs that I then replaced in ROS folder.

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-06-06**:
@jorge : Everything is up to date, when I do apt-get upgrade it does not find anything new. My current version is 0.3.9-0 precise. I don't understand why I still have the error because I have the fix in the hpp file...

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-07**:
Well it seems like my ROS was yet up to date (I upgraded yesterday). But the fix doesn't seem to solve the problem. BTW, is ROS hydro version released as a stable release for Turtlebot2 yet ?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-06-09**:
No, hydro is on development; we just release on groovy. I'm really puzzled. I cannot reproduce the problem in my 32 bits installation, both packages and source installation (after fix). What do you launch exactly? And do you get the same error posted in the answer below?

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-09**:
I launch kobuki_auto_docking compact.launch on the turtlebot's laptop (32 bits). On the workstation computer (64 bits) I run kobuki_auto_docking DockDriveActionClient.py or a client of my own. But, sometimes, the nodes on the turtlebot's computer crash, and it is still the same error.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-09**:
I can check that my sources are up to date too. What exactly did change on source files ? You only add the EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW macro, there is no other changes that I could have missed ?

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-06-09**:
Quite the same for me, whatever I launch (standalone.launch or minimal.launch) it works sometimes but not all the time... And it's perfectly the same error than before.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-10**:
Well, I did not manage to get the error occur again today. So finally, it seems to be fixed. Thank you for your help ! @CarolineQ : did you do a catkin_make clean before you compiled ?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-06-10**:
This is along enough roving discussion, you might consider taking it to the ros-sig-turtlebot mailing list.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-13**:
Finally, as the error is still there, I follow tfoote advice and bring the discussion to the ros-sig-turtlebot mailing list.

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-06-13**:
How do you subscribe to this mailing list ?

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-13**:
The mailing list is at the following web address : groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-sig-turtlebot

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-06-13**:
Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-06-13**:
Thanks a lot.